# How to adjust size of column with pdfmake?

Tags: javascript, json, pdfmake

I'm currently working on a PDF generation with `pdfmake` in client-side, and I've a question : 
I would like to adjust the size of my entire `Column 2` + `A`, `B` blocks, but I can't, even when I put huge values... The goal is to put `Column 2` on top, and `A` and `B` just under it. 
Is there something I'm doing bad ? 
Here is my code (you can try in on : http://pdfmake.org/playground.html )

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        {
            columns: [
                {
                    text: 'Column 1',
                    style: [{bold: true, alignment: 'center'}],
                    width: 45
                },
                [
                    {
                        text: 'Column 2',
                        style: [{bold: true, alignment: 'center'}],
                        width: 200 // Nothing changes..
                    },
                    {
                        columns: [
                            {
                                text: 'A',
                                width: '*',
                                style: [{bold: true, alignment: 'center'}],
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'B',
                                width: '*',
                                style: [{bold: true, alignment: 'center'}],
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                {
                    text: 'Column 3',
                    width: '*',
                    style: [{bold: true, alignment: 'center'}],
                }
            ]
        }   
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you need to use table attribute into content instead of columns. please look into pdfmake/playground.html properly you will surely get an answer. I have uploaded some content from that which is useful to you.

```
        {
        style: 'tableExample',
        color: '#444',
        table: {
            widths: [200, 'auto', 'auto'],
            headerRows: 2,
            // keepWithHeaderRows: 1,
            body: [
                [{text: 'Header with Colspan = 2', style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 2, alignment: 'center'}, {}, {text: 'Header 3', style: 'tableHeader', alignment: 'center'}],
                [{text: 'Header 1', style: 'tableHeader', alignment: 'center'}, {text: 'Header 2', style: 'tableHeader', alignment: 'center'}, {text: 'Header 3', style: 'tableHeader', alignment: 'center'}],
                ['Sample value 1', 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
                [{rowSpan: 3, text: 'rowSpan set to 3\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor'}, 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
                ['', 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
                ['Sample value 1', 'Sample value 2', 'Sample value 3'],
                ['Sample value 1', {colSpan: 2, rowSpan: 2, text: 'Both:\nrowSpan and colSpan\ncan be defined at the same time'}, ''],
                ['Sample value 1', '', ''],
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
                widths: [100, '*', 200, '*'],
                body: [
                    ['width=100', 'star-sized', 'width=200', 'star-sized'],
                    ['fixed-width cells have exactly the specified width', {text: 'nothing interesting here', italics: true, color: 'gray'}, {text: 'nothing interesting here', italics: true, color: 'gray'}, {text: 'nothing interesting here', italics: true, color: 'gray'}]
                ]
            }
        },
```

refer http://pdfmake.org/playground.html this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer might be more helpful to others if you explained how/why it works, and/or why this solution is better than the existing answers that have already been here for a while :)